# Only the checkbox have Backcolor "RED" will be enabled true

Tags: vb.net-2010

I have a 3 `checkboxes` and my `checkboxes` is `.enabled = False`. I want when I click a button, only the `checkboxes` with a red `BackColor` will be set to `enabled = True`

How to do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with something like this :

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    For Each CB As CheckBox In Controls.OfType(Of CheckBox)
        If CB.BackColor = Color.Red Then
            CB.Enabled = True
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

This will loop through all the controls in the form and if the control is of type `CheckBox` then it will check its `BackColor` property and then change to fit your needs, **hope** you understood the code, because `Stackoverflow` is not about giving out ready/full codes, if you didn't understand anything in the code, please feel free to ask about it.

**Hope that helped :)**